# MYSQL returning tables with PHP

Tags: php, sql

I'm confused as to how this works...

I'm trying to assign the table column names into an array in php. I'm trying to do it the same way I do any other query but it's not working. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
$q ="SHOW COLUMNS FROM disp";
$colsq = mysql_query($q);
$c = mysql_fetch_assoc($colsq);
foreach($c['Field'] as $asdf){
    echo $asdf."<br />";
}
```

Comment: Change `$colsq = mysql_query($q);` with `$colsq = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());` and probably you will see error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use mysqli instead of mysql. try this :

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_name);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) 
{
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL:(".$mysqli->connect_errno.")" .$mysqli->connect_error;
}

$q ="SHOW COLUMNS FROM disp";
$res=$mysqli->query($q);

while($data=$res->fetch_assoc())
{
    echo $data['Field']."<br />";
}
```

Comment: +1 for being the first person ever to give me a mysqli example instead of just whining about it. i'm still not switching though. see above comment.

Answer (score 5):

You are doing it wrong, try this.

```
$q = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM disp";
$colsq = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error()); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($colsq)) {
     echo $row['Field']."<br/>";
}
```

**Note:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Thanks captain. They're not even currently working on PHP6 and even when they do it will be months if not years before the majority of people switch to it. i think i'm safe.